# How do I add canonical or any meta head in Magento 2 via CMS Layout XMLs?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have a custom CMS page with the url of /test

I tried pasting this in the Layout Update XML under Page Layout AND also tried under the Custom Theme Layout Update XML.. both options do not work

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sale_campaign_canonical</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

This `sale_campaign_canonical` is a static block available on all storefronts and has

`<link rel="canonical" href="/test" />`

Inside of it

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Use "widgets"

[image]

content > widgets > Add Widget | Type: CMS Block / Design Theme (Your Design)

[image]

Then, in storefront properties, you can choose where you want it to be/load "all Pages" or "All Product Pages" and then select "Page Header".

[image]

Then select your CMS Block

[image]

The new widget functions in Magento 2 are really helpful for putting CMS Blocks where you need. Meta tags, scripts, static information or just about anything. It's really simple, easy to use and you can turn it on or off at will. I used it to add microdata meta tags for condition as well as adding product tabs to certain products/categories. It's very versatile.

Comment: Where is a good reference to see how and where we can add blocks? Like adding things after footers, in head, in DOCTYPE and in body etc.. this is really interesting I will try this now.. the documentation I think is not as friendly...

Comment: I really haven't seen anything that's not so ridiculously complicated or changing files, while almost all of the really good stuff can be done 100% in the backend. I was just playing around and found it and holy cow!

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/jquery-widgets-about.html

That has some interesting information. But without adding any code, you can put in pop-up DIVs for login, or whatever you want really. The one for tabs is complicated, but really amazing and you can add a text attribute when adding products to include only specific tabs per product

Comment: This doesn't work as it adds the canonical tag in the header of the body of the page and will therefore be ignored

Comment: @ChrisRogers You're doing something wrong then if it's adding your CMS to the header and the body.